# Should I stop CSS animations when they are outside viewport

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate

I have a website that relies heavily with CSS transitions/animations using `animate.css` library -> https://www.frasesparavida.com.br

I know browser nowadays do a great job optimizing CSS animations using mainly GPU to avoid bottleneck the CPU. So I was wondering: should I stop manually (using JS) my CSS animations when I detect my animations are outside of the viewport or browser will automatically stop processing those animations?

Most of my animations are done adding/removing classes like `fadeInUp` to elements during some time intervals. So my question is this: does adding those classes (that cause animations) when elements are outside of the viewport cause any significative overhead to the browser? Do browsers "pause" those animations automatically when they are not visible?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, I believe the animations keep running even while not visible. So it's up to you if you want to pause them while not visible, the only reason I can think of for pausing them would be for slower computers and operating systems, but these animations don't seem too intensive for most to handle. If you were to do this just bare in mind that if you do, it is more JS for the browser to run.

Comment: I dont think that's entirely true. A few weeks ago I created a very heavy/intensive CSS animation to check what would happen when I scroll down to some place where the animation was not visible anymore and in CTRL+SHIFT+DEL (of my WINDOWS) I see a drop in CPU (from 70% to 55%). If I scrolled up again it would go up to around 70% again. BUT this only happened with Firefox, with chrome I saw a small drop but it's not too conclusive.

Comment: Just a reminder: with JS animations I dont see any difference in CPU usage if I scroll down the animation! I think most browsers keep running all JS code (wheter it's animations or not), no matter if they are being used in the viewport. HOWEVER with CSS this behaviour seems a lot different. But I am struggling to find some documentation about that...